# Linux software raid

Tags: linux, software-raid

I want to know if I used software raid on Linux for a non system disks (raid 5 as example),then I lost the system for any reason ! can I restore the data on the raid after a fresh installation ??

Answer (score 0):

A set of Linux software raid disks are automatically recognized on any Linux system they are connected to. They contain special metadata that identifies the raid set and which disks belong together so that it's no problem at all to keep working with them.

Comment: Thank you ,I thought that raid configuration saved within the system itself.